# chrome devtools: Revisions of resources not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, you can edit your resources in line and Chrome will generate revisions of that resource. Here the documentation: http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/devtools/docs/elements-styles.html#persist

Sadly, it's not working here, and I don't know how to enable it. It is not possible to expand the file in the resource tab to see the revisions.

Using Chrome 15.0.874.121 on MacOS here. A colleague of mine tried the developer channel, but it's still not there. But I saw a demo of it at the Google Developer Day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in 15.0.874.121 as well -- just double-click on a text content of a CSS or JS file in the Resources panel, type something and press Cmd+Enter. You will see the lines that you added displayed with a green background, and the edited resource on the left will become expandable.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, the Dev channel has an "Edit" button (a pencil with dots) below the resource contents if the resource is editable. You can click it to toggle the resource editing.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on ToT and on dev channel 17.0.942.0 dev.
The scenario.

1. open inspector's Scripts panel
2. start editing with double click
3. save the revision with Cmd+S
4. optional exit from editing mode Shift-Enter
5. open Resource Panel
6. click on the right arrow symbol close to edited file.